# Is it possible to use colors on wordpress site, with an podio script?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, colors, podio

I would like to apply colors to a website page, which contains a code from podio.

e.g. I want to get the word 'geannuleerd' in red.

The data from podio [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25riO.jpg)comes on the page https://huureenacteur.nl/kpc/ through this script:

I understand it doesn't work with css.

How can I take care of that?

Jochanan

the attachement is now plain printscreen, no colors.

i tried with css en and worpress, but i found out that isnt possible afterwards.

I am not that good with css and programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use colors on your WordPress site even with a Podio script.One approach is to use inline styles within your WordPress content, where you can directly apply color styles using the "style" attribute. Another option is to explore WordPress page builders or plugins that offer visual customization options, which can allow you to change colors without delving into code.